# C++/CLI AES 256-bit Encryption

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, c++-cli

Most examples and questions I've found so far is for C# only, however I'm trying to reproduce the following C# code into C++/CLI:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

public byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

    // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
    // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;

            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return encryptedBytes;
}

public byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

    // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
    // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;

            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return decryptedBytes;
}

//Encrypt String
public string EncryptText(string input, string password)
{
    // Get the bytes of the string
    byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

    // Hash the password with SHA256
    passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

    byte[] bytesEncrypted = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);

    string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);

    return result;
}

//Decrypt String
public string DecryptText(string input, string password)
{
    // Get the bytes of the string
    byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

    byte[] bytesDecrypted = AES_Decrypt(bytesToBeDecrypted, passwordBytes);

    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);

    return result;
}
```

This is what I got so far:

```
using namespace System::Security::Cryptography;
using namespace System::IO;

    private: array<unsigned char>^ AES_Encrypt(array<unsigned char>^ bytesToBeEncrypted, array<unsigned char>^ passwordBytes) {
        array<unsigned char>^ encryptedBytes = nullptr;

        // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
        // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
        array<unsigned char>^ saltBytes = gcnew array<unsigned char>(8) { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();
        RijndaelManaged^ AES = gcnew RijndaelManaged();
        auto cs = gcnew CryptoStream(ms, AES->CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode::Write);

        try {
            try {
                AES->KeySize = 256;
                AES->BlockSize = 128;
                AES->Padding = System::Security::Cryptography::PaddingMode::Zeros;

                auto key = gcnew Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                AES->Key = key->GetBytes(AES->KeySize / 8);
                AES->IV = key->GetBytes(AES->BlockSize / 8);

                AES->Mode = CipherMode::CBC;

                try {
                    cs->Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted->Length);
                    cs->Close();
                }
                finally {
                    if (cs != nullptr) delete cs;
                }

                encryptedBytes = ms->ToArray();
            }
            finally {
                if (AES != nullptr) delete AES;
            }
        }
        finally {
         if (ms != nullptr) delete ms;
        }

        return encryptedBytes;
    }

    private: array<unsigned char>^ AES_Decrypt(array<unsigned char>^ bytesToBeDecrypted, array<unsigned char>^ passwordBytes) {
        array<unsigned char>^ decryptedBytes = nullptr;

        // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
        // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
        array<unsigned char>^ saltBytes = gcnew array<unsigned char>(8) { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();
        RijndaelManaged^ AES = gcnew RijndaelManaged();
        auto cs = gcnew CryptoStream(ms, AES->CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode::Write);

        try {
            try {
                AES->KeySize = 256;
                AES->BlockSize = 128;
                AES->Padding = System::Security::Cryptography::PaddingMode::Zeros;

                auto key = gcnew Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                AES->Key = key->GetBytes(AES->KeySize / 8);
                AES->IV = key->GetBytes(AES->BlockSize / 8);

                AES->Mode = CipherMode::CBC;

                try {
                    cs->Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted->Length);
                    cs->Close();
                }
                finally {
                    if (cs != nullptr) delete cs;
                }

                decryptedBytes = ms->ToArray();
            }
            finally {
                if (AES != nullptr) delete AES;
            }
        }
        finally {
         if (ms != nullptr) delete ms;
        }

        return decryptedBytes;
    }

    //Encrypt String
    private: System::String^ EncryptText(System::String^ input, System::String^ password) {
        // Get the bytes of the string
        array<unsigned char>^ bytesToBeEncrypted = System::Text::Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(input);
        array<unsigned char>^ passwordBytes = System::Text::Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(password);

        // Hash the password with SHA256
        passwordBytes = SHA256::Create()->ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

        array<unsigned char>^ bytesEncrypted = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);

        System::String^ result = Convert::ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);

        return result;
    }

    //Decrypt String
    private: System::String^ DecryptText(System::String^ input, System::String^ password) {
        // Get the bytes of the string
        array<unsigned char>^ bytesToBeDecrypted = Convert::FromBase64String(input);
        array<unsigned char>^ passwordBytes = System::Text::Encoding::Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(password);
        passwordBytes = SHA256::Create()->ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

        array<unsigned char>^ bytesDecrypted = AES_Decrypt(bytesToBeDecrypted, passwordBytes);

        System::String^ result = System::Text::Encoding::Encoding::UTF8->GetString(bytesDecrypted);

        return result;
    }
```

The Encryption is working fine, I did a simple test to update it into a label:

```
private: System::Void Button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        System::String^ temp = EncryptText(this->textBox1->Text, "batman");
        this->label1->Text = temp;
        this->label2->Text = DecryptText(temp, "batman");
    }
```

However I'm getting some issues when Decrypting it, I managed to catch the `CryptographicException`:

```
'EncryptionTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll'. 
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.DecryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at EncryptionTest.MyForm.AES_Decrypt(Byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, Byte[] passwordBytes) in C:\Users\[username]\source\repos\EncryptionTest\EncryptionTest\MyForm.h:line 198
```

Line 198 refers to the last try block: `cs->Close();`

I tried all kind of available paddings though, such as `ANSIX923`, `ISO10126`, `PKCS7`, but none helped. I'd appreciate any help you're able to provide.

Comment: To me it looks like you have a method called `AES_Encrypt` in the same class as `EncryptText`, or you have a static method `AES_Encrypt` in another class and you have `using static CLASSNAME;` inside the namespace declaration that the C# code belongs to. In short: you're missing a piece of the C# code.

Comment: @John Nope, actually none methods are missing, here's the whole code in C#: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt

Comment: Yep, and `AES_Encrypt` is defined [at the top of that page](https://imgur.com/Hv5GnWp) under _"Encryption"_... That's where `AES_Encrypt` is coming from.

Comment: @John My bad I didn't even notice that, I'll be closing this question with the final code as the answer, in case I don't manage to get this done, I'll update my question. Thank you.

Comment: @John Question updated, thank you again for the heads up.

Comment: Sorry for my previous (now-deleted) comment, I completely misread your code.

Comment: @John It's ok, any workaround is welcome.

Comment: Your code uses `AES->Padding = System::Security::Cryptography::PaddingMode::Zeros;`  Don't do that.  You are not guaranteed to be able to remove the padding without affecting the original message.  Use PKCS7 for both encryption and decryption.

Comment: @rossum Thank you for the tip, I combined it with Topaco's answer, that's working fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AES parameters are set too late in the C++/CLI code, that is, *after* the creation of [encryptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.createencryptor?view=netcore-3.0#System_Security_Cryptography_SymmetricAlgorithm_CreateEncryptor) and [decryptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.createdecryptor?view=netcore-3.0#System_Security_Cryptography_SymmetricAlgorithm_CreateDecryptor). Therefore, an automatically generated random key and IV and other default values (PKCS7, CBC, etc.) of the `RijndaelManaged` instance are used to create encryptor and decryptor (instead of the key and IV generated with the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` instance and the rest of the specified values). Because of the randomness, key and IV are different for encryption and decryption and thus decryption fails. Therefore, the AES parameters must be set *before* encryptor and decryptor are created, i.e. the correct order is (using the example of encryption):

```
AES->KeySize = 256;
AES->BlockSize = 128;
AES->Mode = CipherMode::CBC;
AES->Padding = System::Security::Cryptography::PaddingMode::Zeros;
auto key = gcnew Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
AES->Key = key->GetBytes(AES->KeySize / 8);
AES->IV = key->GetBytes(AES->BlockSize / 8);
auto cs = gcnew CryptoStream(ms, AES->CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode::Write);
```

By the way, the values for key size, block size and mode correspond to the default values. The default value for padding is PKCS7, which is the more reliable padding compared to zero padding, as already noted in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the only solution which works for me!